# Why LiveServer extension in VS Code does not open the right HTML?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to use LiveServer to quickly live view one HTML file `index.html`, which i created on the fly.
But Everytime I click on button `Go Live` on bottom-right corner of VS Code, it opens another HTML file (under folder `TailwindCSS` in `workspace` .
[image]
What on earth is going on? LiveServer extension is not intuitive at all as its guide shows ! This malfunctioning LiveServer extension has wasted me 1 hour !!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Right click on html file]

Right-click the main file you want to open in the live server and click on "Open with live server". This might work.

Comment: already tired many times. when I right-click, there was no option `Open with LiveServer` for the HTML file that I want to open with LiveServer. But `Open with LiveServer` is available for those HTML files under VSCode workspace.  I feel that `workspace` concept in VSCode might be the silly guy who messed up everything.

Comment: Yeah, really weird. I personally never had any problems with live server, and I used it a lot. Maybe it has to do with your project not being marked as safe, as this is a fairly new vs code "feature"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just had to open the whole folder via File->Open Folder.

Answer (score 0):

one has to save html file as in extension for example **header.html** then when when you click on golive it appears in the default server like chrome in mine

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34642809)

Comment: The OP already had code in a file with a correct extension.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

happened to me too, Turns out live server was trying to open another index.html in a completely different working directory. i was connected remotely to wsl and I used the terminal to change the directory but visual studio explorer had opened the directory i was working on before. That was the issue, Since then I'm starting vscode and opening my home folder through the browser, so I can cd around using the terminal as I desire but if and when I need live server, live server opens my home older and lists the directories, so i just manually go to the location my index.html is located. It is less frustrating than seeing live server render a previous project i've been working on

Answer (score 0):

#### Background

The VS Code Live Serve extension's server-side uses an npm package called [`send`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/send) to attempt to serve files **from the local filesystem, within the current workspace**. You can see the dependencies in [its `package.json` file](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/master/lib/live-server/package.json), and the code for the server-side of the Live Server extension in [its `lib/live-server/index.js` file](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/master/lib/live-server/index.js).

If the editor area of VS Code has UI focus, and the currently focused editor tab is an HTML file, then Live Server will open to that HTML document upon going live. The `files.exclude` setting has no effect on this. The file must be part of the currently opened workspace for this to work.

Live Server doesn't change the default behaviour for [the `index` property](https://github.com/pillarjs/send#index) of its `send` configuration, so if you request a directory containing a file named `index.html`, then that file will be served instead of the directory UI provided by `serve-index`. The `files.exclude` setting has no effect on this.

If there is no file named `index.html` in the directory specified by the `liveServer.settings.root` VS Code setting contributed by the Live Server extension (which has a default value of `"/"`, meaning the currently open VS Code workspace folder), then it will serve a directory UI for that directory. So,

- If you have not touched the `liveServer.settings.root` setting (which has a default value of `"/"`, meaning the currently open VS Code workspace folder), and have purposely put the `index.html` file that you want to be opened upon going live in a subdirectory (Ex. `./foo/bar/baz/`) of your VS Code workspace folder, then you will need to set the `liveServer.settings.root` setting to `"/foo/bar/baz"` in your workspace [.vscode/settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).
- If the file you want to be opened upon going live is not called `index.html`, you will either need to name it that, or create a symlink with that name to that file.

You can also do more complicated directory mappings using the `liveServer.settings.mount` setting.

If you're interested in looking at some log messages for the server side, at the time of this writing, Live Server's server side prints such messages into the developer console of VS Code, which you can view by opening the VS Code devtools using the `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). Not sure why it uses that console instead of an [`OutputChannel`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#OutputChannel).

#### In this particular case

I think the problem here is that your index file isn't under any of the root workspace folders you have open in your current workspace (it's a new, unsaved multi-root workspace, but that shouldn't matter. the problem is the index.html file not being inside any of its roots).

Comment: note: most of this post is copied from [this other post of mine](/a/77176224/11107541), answering a different question.